# Shadow on hover of Grid Cell in google Appmaker similar to Hangout call Profile Pic hover

Tags: google-app-maker

I have a Grid Widget which shows up Items names and Image link in the Data Table in its Grid Cells.When I hover on the Grid Cell, I want a shadow to appear with the Item Description in the Data table. Please suggest how can I achieve it.

Comment: Please review the steps in how to ask a question and see if you can improve your question by providing examples of things you've tried or techniques you've already researched, etc.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve desired behavior by following these steps:

1. Add a panel inside your cell
2. Layout the panel to cover entire cell (set top, bottom, left, right
   to 0 and width height to auto OR 'fill parent' both for width and
   height if you are using flex layout)
3. Add widgets you need (label with description) to this 'hover' panel
4. Uncheck 'visible' panel's property
5. Add CSS styles to show panel on cell mouse hover

> ```
> .app-Items-GridItemsCell:hover .app-Items-PanelHover {
>   display: flex !important;
>   opacity: 0.5;
> }
> ```

That should make the trick. Here is a link to the sample app:
[AM Cell Hover Effect](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxtQI4fTAVQqRFdXR0ZVLTJDdVk)